# Why does |sortBy:random work with Angular 1.0.1 but not in 1.2.26?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

This simple random function used to work well in Angular 1.0.1:

http://jsfiddle.net/edwardtanguay/4af5Lr69/1/

But when I have Angular 1.2.26 loaded, it gets the error

> Error: [$rootScope:infdig]...

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <p ng-repeat="i in list|orderBy:random">{{i}}</p>
</div>
```

---

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];
    $scope.random = function() {
        return 0.5 - Math.random();
    }
}
```

**What do I have to do to get this to work in Angular 1.2.26?**

Comment: Can't you just shuffle the list in your controller?

Comment: what is the expectation of using `orderBy:random`?

Comment: to randomize the order of the items, it works in Angular 1.0.1 e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/edwardtanguay/n2q1rbrL/

Comment: check this one http://jsfiddle.net/4qLzv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is because `digest cycle` is executing more than 10 iterations consecutively.

If we define as `<p ng-repeat="i in list| orderBy:random">{{i}}</p>` then `random()` function will call each and every repeat and also after that. This is angular angular [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig) describe the issue.

You can use something like below to increase the digest cycle limit, but it will be a performance issue.

```
var app = angular.module('app', [], function($rootScopeProvider) {
     $rootScopeProvider.digestTtl(10000);
});
```

here is the [DOC](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$rootScopeProvider)

If you can use something like this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/4qLzv/), use it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why it works in earlier version but the reason it doesn't work now is that digests are complex and a single scope change can generate numerous digests. Anything that changes the scope again from within the digest will generate new digest(s) to reconcile that scope change.

Consider that digests aren't a one time operation, they are a cycle that stops when all watches are reconciled.

By using a function in view that returns random sort value, it will return a new value each digest therefore creating an infinite loop.

Also note that using the development version of angular ( not the min version) will give more verbose error output and stack trace